# How to apply referrerpolicy attribute with Lazyload with jQuery

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I set Lazyload script with jQuery with this code in my footer

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("img.lazy").lazyload({
    threshold : 10,
    effect : "fadeIn",
    });
    });
</script>
```

And this is my HTML part of lazyload

```
<a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank" width="100%" height="100%">
<img class="lazy" src="//example.jpg" data-original="//example.jpg" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
</a>
```

If I test without lazyload, refererpolicy works fine, but If I set with lazyload it seems that referrerpolicy attribute is not working. Is there any ways to set lazyload and refererpolicy together?

Comment: Can you let us know *which* `lazyload` plugin you're using?

Comment: @freedomn-m I use jQuery Lazyload plugin in 1.9.1 version

Comment: Can you provide a complete snippet that demonstrates the issue?  A *quick* look at something called lazyload v 1.91 shows that all it does to load the image is `$self.attr("src", original);` - ie .src=data-original.  A quick testing by setting .src shows that referrerpolicy is applied when setting .src=  https://jsfiddle.net/d954qtrm/ **edit** updating that fiddle to use lazyload does indeed change the referrerpolicy: https://jsfiddle.net/d954qtrm/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lazyload 1.9.1](https://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/) loads images in the background then updates your image with the background-loaded image.   This allows it to provide a "loading..." type placeholder for when images take some time to load, rather than use the default browser image-not-found or image-loading image.

Lazyload does this with:

```
$("<img/>")[0].src = ...
```

ie, an *in-memory* image tag that doesn't exist in the DOM.   When the `load` event of that in-memory image fires, lazyload then sets your img tag's src to the same as that of the in-memory image, thus using the cached version of the image.

As the `$("<img/>")` does not have a referrerpolicy, you get the default *for that in-memory image tag*:  `strict-origin-when-cross-origin`.

The solution is to amend lazyload.js, line 105 to:

```
$("<img />", { referrerpolicy: $(this).attr("referrerpolicy") })
```

(there may need to be other checks as lazyload also works on non-images with `background-image`)

Obviously you then won't be able to use a CDN.  Sample fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d954qtrm/2/

---

Note that [lazyload v2.0](https://github.com/tuupola/lazyload) does not use an in-memory `img` tag so does not have the same problem and uses the source img referrerpolicy: https://jsfiddle.net/d954qtrm/3/